# What is the replacement for dateutil.parser in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dateutil

Python 2.x has a great function called dateutil.parser which turns an ISO8601 formatted date into a python datetime value. It's not present in Python 3. What is the replacement?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

dateutil is a third party module. It has recently been ported to Python 3 with dateutil 2.0, and the parser functions was ported as well.

So the replacement is `dateutil.parser`. You just forgot to install it.

Comment: I thought that dateutil was installed by default on Python 2?

Comment: `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: You need to do `from dateutil import parser` to get that module directly because `import dateutil` has a spartan `__init__.py` and will not give you `dateutil.parser` as you might expect.

Comment: Apparently, I have it installed since I am able to `import dateutil` in python, but not in python3: https://pastebin.com/7AS78rt2. Is there some command line flag that I have to pass to pip to install it for python3 as well?

Comment: @SergiyBelozorov try `python3 -m pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: pip3 install python-dateutil

Answer (score 14):

You should first find the exact name for the module using pip search:

```
pip search dateutil
```

Then, install the version you want (assuming py-dateutil):

```
pip install py-dateutil
```

Now, fire-up shell and import the module (pitfall: the module is not called py-dateutil):

```
import dateutil.parser
```

You should be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this through the `datetime` module's `strptime` method.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> mydate = datetime.datetime(2002,12,4, 12, 30).isoformat()
>>> mydate
'2002-12-04T12:30:00'
>>> parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime( mydate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" )
>>> parsed_date
datetime.datetime(2002, 12, 4, 12, 30)
```

`strptime` has a flexible set of options as to parsing your date. See [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information.

Comment: True, but there's no easy way to handle the Z suffix vs. a +/- offset. That requires additional coding. But I guess I'm going to have to do that.

Comment: Downvote because this code only handles a very special, simple case of the ISO8601 standard and will crash on any other valid ISO8601 formatted date string. The question referes to the ISO8601 standard in general.

Comment: Agree with the above: as soon as you give `strptime()` an explicit format string, the input string _must_ be in that exact format. If any part is not in the input string (e.g. no offset specified if format string contains `%z`, it will raise an exception.